# jquery $(this).serialize() not working right

Tags: jquery, json, forms, serialization, this

```
&mobile=0400000000¬es=this+is+a+test
```

The error is above

You will see that the following has occurred ¬es

It should of been `&notes=`

i am wondering why this has happened.

here is the form HTML

```
<!---left--->
<div class="leadwidth">
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="MYSQL"/>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="newlead"/>
<input type="hidden" name="fetchform" value="leadstores"/>
<input type="hidden" id="userid" name="userid" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="usertype" name="usertype" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="customerid" name="customerid" value=""/>

  <div class="formbg">Trading Name:<input name="tradingname"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Postal Street Address:<input name="streetaddress"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Postal Suburb:<input name="suburb"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Postal State:<select name="state"><option value="0">--Please Select--</option></select></div>

<div class="formbg">Postal Postcode:<input name="postcode"/></div>


<div class="formbg">Category:<select name="category"><option value="0">--Please Select--</option></select></div>

<div class="formbg formheight">Sub-Category:<select name="subcategory" MULTIPLE><option value="0">--Please Select--</option></select></div>

<div class="formbg">Membership:<input name="cmembership"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Sales Status:<select name="salesstatus"><option value="0">--Please Select--</option></select></div>

<div id="managerstatus" class="formbg">Manager Status:<select name="managerstatus"><option value="0">--Please Select--</option></select></div>

<div id="hqstatus" class="formbg">HQ Status:<select name="hqstatus"><option value="0">--Please Select--</option></select></div>

<div id="publishtoweb" class="formbg">Publish 2 Web:<select name="publishtoweb"><option value="0">--Please Select--</option></select></div>


</div>
<!---middle--->
<div class="leadwidth">
<div class="formbg">Title:<select name="title"><option value="0">--Please Select--</option></select></div>

<div class="formbg">First Name:<input name="firstname"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Last Name:<input name="lastname"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Position:<input name="position"/></div>
<div class="formbg">Web Address:<input name="webaddress"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Business Description:</div>
<textarea name="businessdescription"></textarea>

<button type="submit" id="newsubmit" class="blacksavebutton"></button>
</div>
<!---Far Right--->
<div class="leadwidth">
<div class="formbg">Company Name:<input name="companyname"/></div>

<div class="formbg">ABN/ACN:<input name="abnacn"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Email:<input name="email"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Phone Number:<input name="phonenumber"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Mobile Number:<input name="mobile"/></div>

<div class="formbg">Notes:</div>
<textarea name="notes"></textarea>
<img src="http://realcashback.com.au/v2/system/template/images/newleads/stepone_newlead.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: $(this)? what? . maybe you need to use form if you want to use submit..

Comment: it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/zPJLg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you determining this?

What you see, `¬`, is the entity for `&not;`.

Is the actual server-received input correct?

If you are outputting this on a webpage, the entites may be converted. It may actually be fine on the server.

Edit based on OP comment:

```
$("#log ").html($(this).serialize());
```

Doesn't escape the html entities. To get around this, use:

```
$("#log ").text($(this).serialize()).html();
```

Comment: this is what the server is returning when I do the following $("#log
").html($(this).serialize());

Comment: Thanks tadeck, but you overwrote my own edit with additional information. Please wait until the answer is "inactive" to clean up others formatting

Comment: @RussellHarrower That is javascript with the output viewed on the webpage, not necessarily what the server is receiving. I'll edit with a solution.